# Selenium *read* text in prompt

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

We're using Selenium for implementing web tests. In one scenario, our application comes up with a browser prompt. It is possible to handle browser prompts with:

```
var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.Accept(); // accept prompt
alert.Dismiss(); // dismiss prompt
alert.Text; // get text from prompt
alert.SendKeys("text"); // fill out the input element on the prompt
```

Is there any chance we can *read* the pre-published text from the input element?

Comment: what do you mean by pre-published text ? if you are using Java you can use AlertElem.getText() to get the text.

Comment: .getText (or in case of C#: .Text) returns the "prompt text", however, some prompts have an additional input element on them. I want to read the content of that input element.

Comment: The code for the [JavaScript `prompt()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt) which displays this type of dialog looks like this: `window.prompt("prompt text", "default value");`. This will display a prompt value with the text of "prompt text", and the input box where the user is expected to type the value prepopulated with "default value". The `Alert.getText()` method returns the prompt text; there is no way to get the default value at the moment.

Comment: As you are a core contributor of Selenium: is there a technical reason why the default value cannot be retrieved at the moment? Is this a planned feature? Does it make sense to file a feature request?

Comment: A feature request in the issue tracker would likely be the way to go here. There isn't any technical reason, except that it's not widely useful in the large percentage of cases. In the case where you need to check the default value, you could always simply accept the alert without using `sendKeys`, and validate that the value is correct in the application being automated and that the value is the default you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript code for the [`prompt()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt) which displays this type of dialog looks like this:

```
window.prompt("prompt text", "default value");
```

This will display a dialog box with a label and an input text box where the user is expected to type the value. In the example above, the label will have the text of "prompt text"; the input box will be prepopulated with "default value". The WebDriver `Alert.getText()` method returns the prompt text, but you're right, there is no way to get the default value at the moment.