# How to get Javascript prompt value with Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

In my page I open a prompt with the following code:

```
prompt('CopyURL','http://www.google.com');
```

In protractor I can get the text but I don't know how to get the value. For getting the text I use the following code:

```
var alertDialog = browser.switchTo().alert();
expect(alertDialog.getText()).toEqual('Copy URL');
```

How do I get `'http://www.google.com'` with protractor?

Thank you!!

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890344/selenium-read-text-in-prompt). It doesn't like this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to do it. However, prompt's were designed for user to enter a value rather than get the value that you pass in the html code. If you are using the value that's passed in the prompt some where in your DOM, then you can get the value of that element and verify with the passed element. Here's a sample method -

HTML Code -

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Open Prompt</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Javascript Code -

```
function myFunction() {
    var val = prompt("Name", "abc");
    if (val != null) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = val;
    }
}
```

As demonstrated above, you can get the value passed to the prompt by verifying the value stored in the **p** element of html. However if you just want to show a value to the user, in this case your url, then a normal alert should be considered in place of prompt i believe. Hope it helps.

Comment: I would prefer not to modify the page for test purposes. But if this is the only solution I'd consider it. Thanks

Comment: I feel so. However you never know what software can do. You can play with it anyway you want. Who knows Selenium might implement it soon enough.

Comment: How to add value in prompt from protractor?